# Does WebAPI encompass OData?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm a little confused.

This article (http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/03/22/bringing-odata-to-your-webapi-just-use-iqueryable/) says all that is needed to be done to support OData is to change IEnumerable to IQuerable for the return type.

I read somewhere else that I have to include the OData package (http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.odata) in order to support OData in my WebAPI project.

Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this package. Take a look at the [`following tutorial`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/getting-started-with-odata-in-web-api/create-a-read-only-odata-endpoint).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Comment: The link I have provided is to a reliable source (`http://asp.net`) and link rot is unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 1):

The first version had very limited OData capabiltiies. ASP.NET 2012.2 expands on these capabilties. Technically, neither provides all the features described in the OData V3 spec.